# How do I create an interface with buttons and text?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, interface, applet

I've tried different ways of creating different interfaces and applets. One of the main things I'm  trying to do is to get these gui's to display text and show multiple buttons with different text leading to different outcomes. What I'm asking is, what code is necessary to create an applet or an interface (because I fail at telling the difference between the two) and how should I approach building and structuring that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use netbeans because it has an editor and is the easy way to create Applet.

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

Answer (score 0):

You have three main choices I can think of, others will for sure think of something else:

- Create a web server and actually serve a web site with your interface. You can code the interface yourself and communicate with your java server using ajax, you can let [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) among others do that for you. COnsider also frameworks like [Struts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Struts)
- Create an applet which will become an embedded object in a web site. This is quickly falling out of grace, and I'd strongly discourage you from doing it, if only because of the pains of java plugins in the browser
- Create an application with an interface by using AWT or Swing (which come with Java) or, and this is my personal opinion, more elegantly with [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/)

It's hard to tell what will best help you without knowing more of your requirements, but if you are going web, I'd suggest you check out GWT, and if you are going desktop app, look into SWT. Also, please understand these are all well tested frameworks and my preferences are just that, preferences.

Answer (score 0):

To create an interface in eclipse using java you can use swing.

In eclipse:

1. Create a new Java Project (File -> New -> Java Project).
2. Right Click on `src` folder and click New -> Other -> WindowBuilder -> Swing Designer -> [Application Window]/[JApplet].
3. Add the components that you want (buttons, textfields...).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like your trying to graduate from console programs to GUI programs. A GUI works differently from a console program. A console program you have a bunch of loops and if statements, but a GUI program work completely differently.  The main difference is that GUI programs are event driven.

With that being said, you want to choose a GUI framework, like Swing. Then decide if you want your application to be web based or desktop. An applet is more for web. If you want a desktop program, then you want a JFrame which will be the top-level container of your application.

You can learn all the components that are available to you in the standard Swing API [**here**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html). IMO it seems like you need to start from the beginnging, so I would start from the very being of [**How to Create GUIs with Swing**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/). You will want to pay close attention to section on [**Writing Event Listeners**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html)

If you *do* want to create an Applet instead of a desktop program, you can see the [**Applets**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html), where you'll learn how to develop Applets and how to deploy them. You will still need to learn some basics though from the Swing link I mentioned.

Also, before you start using drag and drop gui builder tools, I would strongly urge you to first learn to hand code. It will work best for you in the long run.

I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The defacto world standard GUI for all platforms is becoming Html5 and css3.

So the easiest way for you to write an interface is in HTML. You don't need an applet unless you have real specific needs like having a constant connection to the server for a chat or whatever. Anyway most of the applet reasons to exist are now resolved in standard HTML. If you want to learn a new langue, try Dart (dartlang.org)

You could use dart to have the more adaptable GUI to standards in the world

I explain why in this blog post
http://1veu.blogspot.com/2013/12/why-i-think-dart-will-detrone-java.html

Naturally even if you need to write a stand alone application with native GUI, HTML5 and css3 are still widely employed along with webkit or native code transformers like PhoneGap.